# Fragment shows up empty on the second click of an item from a RecyclerView while using FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

In my app, when I click on an item (Issue) in a RecyclerView which uses FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter to paginate data from Firebase realtime database, it displays details about the item clicked in another fragment (using navigation component). This works fine on the first click, however when I return to the previous fragment and click the same item on the RecyclerView a second time, the details of the item are not shown.

Because I use safe args to pass the item id (issueId) to the next fragment which it uses to query the firebase realtime database and retrieve the details to be displayed, I decide to log the item id to my console in onViewCreated() just to be sure that the item id is being passed on the second click and also that the details (names of user who added an issue) are being retrieved from the database, but just not showing. Then, I noticed a weird behaviour.

On the first click, the item id is logged to the console, the details are logged to the console as well and the fragment displays the details. However on the second click, the item id is logged to the console (showing that the item id is being passed as should be the case), but the details are not logged to the console and not displayed in the fragment (hence the fragment shows up empty). Now the weird part, when I navigate back to the previous fragment, then I see a log of the details displayed twice.

Another strange thing I noticed is that, every item on the RecyclerView has this weird behaviour except the last item. The last item displays its details on the second click, but any other item I click doesn't.

I also noticed that the log shows the details for every item I have previously clicked twice when I navigate back even though I am clicking on a different item

I changed the adapter from FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, everything works fine. When I change back to using FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter, the same problem exists.

Is this a bug in my code or FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter itself. What could be the problem and what can I do to fix it?

Below is the FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter:

```
package com.colley.android.adapter

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.colley.android.R
import com.colley.android.databinding.ItemIssueBinding
import com.colley.android.model.Issue
import com.colley.android.model.Profile
import com.firebase.ui.database.paging.DatabasePagingOptions
import com.firebase.ui.database.paging.FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.getValue
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase

class IssuesPagingAdapter(
    options: DatabasePagingOptions<Issue>,
    private val context: Context,
    private val currentUser: FirebaseUser?,
    private val clickListener: IssuePagingItemClickedListener
) : FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<Issue, IssuePagingViewHolder>(options) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IssuePagingViewHolder {
        val viewBinding = ItemIssueBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return IssuePagingViewHolder(viewBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: IssuePagingViewHolder, position: Int, model: Issue) {
        viewHolder.bind(currentUser, model, context, clickListener)
    }

    interface IssuePagingItemClickedListener {
        fun onItemClick(issueId: String, view: View)
        fun onItemLongCLicked(issueId: String, view: View)
        fun onUserClicked(userId: String, view: View)
    }


}


class IssuePagingViewHolder (private val itemBinding : ItemIssueBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    fun bind(
        currentUser: FirebaseUser?,
        issue: Issue, context: Context,
        clickListener: IssuesPagingAdapter.IssuePagingItemClickedListener) = with(itemBinding) {

        //set issue title, body, timeStamp, contributions and endorsements count
        issueTitleTextView.text = issue.title
        issueBodyTextView.text = issue.body
        issueTimeStampTextView.text = issue.timeStamp
        contributionsTextView.text = issue.contributionsCount.toString()
        endorsementTextView.text = issue.endorsementsCount.toString()

        //check if userId is not null
        issue.userId?.let { userId ->
            //retrieve user profile
            Firebase.database.reference.child("profiles").child(userId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        val profile = snapshot.getValue<Profile>()
                       if (profile != null) {
                           //set the name of user who raised this issue
                           userNameTextView.text = profile.name
                           //set the school of the user who raised this issue
                           userSchoolTextView.text = profile.school
                       }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                }
            )

            //retrieve user photo
            Firebase.database.reference.child("photos").child(userId)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        val photo = snapshot.getValue<String>()
                        //set photo
                        if (photo != null) {
                            Glide.with(root.context).load(photo)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).into(userImageView)
                        } else {
                            Glide.with(root.context).load(R.drawable.ic_person).into(userImageView)
                        }
                    }

                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                }
            )
        }
        

        root.setOnClickListener {
            if(issue.issueId != null) {
                clickListener.onItemClick(issue.issueId, it)
            }
        }

        root.setOnLongClickListener {
            if(issue.issueId != null) {
                clickListener.onItemLongCLicked(issue.issueId, it)
            }
            true
        }

        userNameTextView.setOnClickListener {
            if(issue.userId != null) {
                clickListener.onUserClicked(issue.userId, it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the fragment to display the item details:

```
package com.colley.android.view.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.*
import android.view.View.GONE
import android.view.View.VISIBLE
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.colley.android.R
import com.colley.android.adapter.IssuesCommentsRecyclerAdapter
import com.colley.android.databinding.FragmentViewIssueBinding
import com.colley.android.model.Comment
import com.colley.android.model.Issue
import com.colley.android.model.Profile
import com.colley.android.view.dialog.IssueCommentBottomSheetDialogFragment
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions
import com.firebase.ui.database.ObservableSnapshotArray
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.getValue
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase


class ViewIssueFragment :
    Fragment(),
    IssuesCommentsRecyclerAdapter.ItemClickedListener,
    IssuesCommentsRecyclerAdapter.DataChangedListener {

    private val args: ViewIssueFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    private var _binding: FragmentViewIssueBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding
    private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var currentUser: FirebaseUser
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var commentSheetDialog: IssueCommentBottomSheetDialogFragment
    private var issue: Issue? = null
    private var adapter: IssuesCommentsRecyclerAdapter? = null
    private var manager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
    private val uid: String
        get() = currentUser.uid


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentViewIssueBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        recyclerView = binding?.issuesCommentsRecyclerView!!
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //initialize Realtime Database
        dbRef = Firebase.database.reference

        //initialize authentication
        auth = Firebase.auth

        //initialize currentUser
        currentUser = auth.currentUser!!

        //log item id
        Log.d("Log itemId", args.issueId)

        //get a query reference to issue comments //order by time stamp
        val commentsRef = dbRef.child("issues").child(args.issueId)
            .child("comments").orderByChild("commentTimeStamp")

        //the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter class and options come from the FirebaseUI library
        //build an options to configure adapter. setQuery takes firebase query to listen to and a
        //model class to which snapShots should be parsed
        val options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Comment>()
            .setQuery(commentsRef, Comment::class.java)
            .build()

        //initialize issue comments adapter
        adapter = IssuesCommentsRecyclerAdapter(
            options,
            currentUser,
            this,
            this,
            requireContext())
        manager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        //reversing layout and stacking fron end so that the most recent comments appear at the top
        manager?.reverseLayout = true
        manager?.stackFromEnd = true
        recyclerView.layoutManager = manager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        dbRef.child("issues").child(args.issueId).addValueEventListener(
            object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    issue = snapshot.getValue<Issue>()
                    if(issue != null) {

                        //listener for contrbutions count used to set count text
                        dbRef.child("issues").child(args.issueId)
                            .child("contributionsCount").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                            object : ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                    val count = snapshot.getValue<Int>()
                                    if(count != null) {
                                        binding?.contributionsTextView?.text = count.toString()
                                    }
                                }

                                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                            }
                        )

                        //listener for endorsement counts used to set endorsement count text
                        dbRef.child("issues").child(args.issueId)
                            .child("endorsementsCount").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                            object : ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                    val count = snapshot.getValue<Int>()
                                    if(count != null) {
                                        binding?.endorsementTextView?.text = count.toString()
                                    }
                                }

                                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {} }
                        )

                        //set issue title, body and time stamp, these don't need to change
                        binding?.issueTitleTextView?.text = issue?.title
                        binding?.issueBodyTextView?.text = issue?.body
                        binding?.issueTimeStampTextView?.text = issue?.timeStamp.toString()

                        //listener for user photo
                        dbRef.child("photos").child(issue?.userId.toString())
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                            object : ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                    val photo = snapshot.getValue<String>()
                                    if(photo != null) {
                                        context?.let { context -> binding?.userImageView?.let {
                                                imageView ->
                                            Glide.with(context).load(photo).into(
                                                imageView
                                            )
                                        } }
                                    } else {
                                        context?.let { context -> binding?.userImageView?.let {
                                                imageView ->
                                            Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_profile).into(
                                                imageView
                                            )
                                        } }
                                    }
                                }

                                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                            }
                        )

                        //listener for profile to set name and school
                        dbRef.child("profiles").child(issue?.userId.toString())
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                            object : ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                    val profile = snapshot.getValue<Profile>()
                                    if (profile != null) {
                                        
                                        //log name details to console
                                        profile.name?.let { Log.d("Log Details", it) }

                                        binding?.userNameTextView?.text = profile.name
                                        binding?.userSchoolTextView?.text = profile.school
                                    }
                                }

                                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
            }
        )

        binding?.commentLinearLayout?.setOnClickListener {
            commentSheetDialog = IssueCommentBottomSheetDialogFragment(
                requireContext(),
                requireView())
            commentSheetDialog.arguments = bundleOf("issueIdKey" to args.issueId)
            commentSheetDialog.show(parentFragmentManager, null)
        }

        binding?.endorseLinearLayout?.setOnClickListener {
            //update contributions count
            dbRef.child("issues").child(args.issueId).child("endorsementsCount")
                .runTransaction(
                object : Transaction.Handler {
                    override fun doTransaction(currentData: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                        //retrieve the current value of endorsement count at this location
                        var endorsementsCount = currentData.getValue<Int>()
                        if (endorsementsCount != null) {
                            //increase the count by 1
                            endorsementsCount++
                            //reassign the value to reflect the new update
                            currentData.value = endorsementsCount
                        }
                        //set database issue value to the new update
                        return Transaction.success(currentData)
                    }

                    override fun onComplete(
                        error: DatabaseError?,
                        committed: Boolean,
                        currentData: DataSnapshot?
                    ) {
                        if (error == null && committed) {
                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Endorsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    }

                }
            )
        }

        //view profile when clicked
        binding?.userImageView?.setOnClickListener {
            val action = issue?.userId?.let { it1 ->
                ViewIssueFragmentDirections.actionViewIssueFragmentToUserInfoFragment(it1)
            }
            if (action != null) {
                parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)
            }
        }

        //view user profile when clicked
        binding?.userNameTextView?.setOnClickListener {
            val action = issue?.userId?.let { it1 ->
                ViewIssueFragmentDirections.actionViewIssueFragmentToUserInfoFragment(it1)
            }
            if (action != null) {
                parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onItemClick(comment: Comment, view: View) {
        //expand comment
    }

    override fun onItemLongCLicked(comment: Comment, view: View) {
        //create option to delete
        //create option to respond
    }

    //view user profile
    override fun onUserClicked(userId: String, view: View) {
        val action = ViewIssueFragmentDirections.actionViewIssueFragmentToUserInfoFragment(userId)
        parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter?.startListening()
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter?.stopListening()
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onDataAvailable(snapshotArray: ObservableSnapshotArray<Comment>) {
        //dismiss progress bar once snapshot is available
        binding?.issuesCommentProgressBar?.visibility = GONE

        //show that there are no comments if snapshot is empty else hide view
        //show recycler view if snapshot is not empty else hide
        if (snapshotArray.isEmpty()) {
            binding?.noCommentsLayout?.visibility = VISIBLE
        } else {
            binding?.noCommentsLayout?.visibility = GONE
            binding?.issuesCommentsRecyclerView?.visibility = VISIBLE
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the fragment with the recyclerView showing how I have initialised the adapter:

```
package com.colley.android.view.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.view.View.GONE
import android.view.View.VISIBLE
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.paging.LoadState
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import com.colley.android.R
import com.colley.android.adapter.IssuesPagingAdapter
import com.colley.android.databinding.FragmentIssuesBinding
import com.colley.android.model.Issue
import com.firebase.ui.database.paging.DatabasePagingOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.google.firebase.database.ktx.database
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class IssuesFragment :
    Fragment(),
    IssuesPagingAdapter.IssuePagingItemClickedListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentIssuesBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var currentUser: FirebaseUser
    private var adapter: IssuesPagingAdapter? = null
    private var manager: LinearLayoutManager? = null
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout
    private val uid: String
        get() = currentUser.uid

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //fragment can participate in populating the options menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        //initialize Realtime Database
        dbRef = Firebase.database.reference

        //initialize authentication
        auth = Firebase.auth

        //initialize currentUser
        currentUser = auth.currentUser!!
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu.clear()
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.isssues_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.search_issues_menu_item -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Searching issues", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentIssuesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        recyclerView = binding.issueRecyclerView
        swipeRefreshLayout = binding.swipeRefreshLayout
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //get a query reference to issues 
        val issuesQuery = dbRef.child("issues")

        //configuration for how the FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter should load pages
        val config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 30,
            prefetchDistance = 15,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        )

        //Options to configure an FirebasePagingAdapter
        val options = DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<Issue>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)
            .setQuery(issuesQuery, config, Issue::class.java)
            .setDiffCallback(object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataSnapshot>() {
                override fun areItemsTheSame(
                    oldItem: DataSnapshot,
                    newItem: DataSnapshot
                ): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.getValue(Issue::class.java)?.issueId == newItem.getValue(Issue::class.java)?.issueId
                }

                override fun areContentsTheSame(
                    oldItem: DataSnapshot,
                    newItem: DataSnapshot
                ): Boolean {
                    return oldItem.getValue(Issue::class.java) == newItem.getValue(Issue::class.java)
                }

            })
            .build()

        //instantiate adapter
        adapter = IssuesPagingAdapter(
            options,
            requireContext(),
            currentUser,
            this)

        //Perform some action every time data changes or when there is an error.
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            adapter?.loadStateFlow?.collectLatest { loadStates ->

                when (loadStates.refresh) {
                    is LoadState.Error -> {

                        // The initial load failed. Call the retry() method
                        // in order to retry the load operation.
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error fetching issues! Retrying..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        //display no posts available at the moment
                        binding.noIssuesLayout.visibility = VISIBLE
                        adapter?.retry()
                    }
                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        // The initial Load has begun
                        // ...
                        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
                    }
                    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                        // The previous load (either initial or additional) completed
                        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                        //remove display no posts available at the moment
                        binding.noIssuesLayout.visibility = GONE

                    }
                }

                when (loadStates.append) {
                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        // The additional load failed. Call the retry() method
                        // in order to retry the load operation.
                        adapter?.retry()
                    }
                    is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        // The adapter has started to load an additional page
                        // ...
                        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = true
                    }
                    is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                        if (loadStates.append.endOfPaginationReached) {
                            // The adapter has finished loading all of the data set
                            swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //set recycler view layout manager
        manager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        recyclerView.layoutManager = manager

        //initialize adapter
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener {
            adapter?.refresh()
        }

    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }

    //navigate to new fragment with issue id
    override fun onItemClick(issueId: String, view: View) {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToViewIssueFragment(issueId)
        parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)

    }

    override fun onItemLongCLicked(issueId: String, view: View) {
    }

    override fun onUserClicked(userId: String, view: View) {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToUserInfoFragment(userId)
        parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(action)
    }

}
```

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0LON.png)

[After first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqcVP.png)

[After second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aaG3.png)

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **700 (seven hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: My bad! I figured the bug. I should have used addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead of addValueEventListener to query the item details (issue) from the database in the fragment that displays the clicked item details, otherwise remove the addValueEventListener in onStop() so that the listener is no longer attached to the database when I navigate back to the previous fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` to query the item details (issue) from the database in the fragment that displays the clicked item details. Otherwise, remove the `addValueEventListener` in `onStop()` so that the listener is no longer attached to the database when navigating back to the previous fragment.